# Многоразовое копирование

Tags: c#, clipboard

Задача:
Запустить программу.
Все то, что было скопировано за время работы программы - сохранять в листе.
По нажатию на кнопку - скопировать всё, что было сохранено в лист в буффер обмена.

Т.е. сделать такого рода многомерное копирование.
Как лучше такое реализовать?

Comment: Ну вы уже как-то пробовали и у вас не получилось?

Comment: Пытался найти информацию по поводу событий копирования - без успехов, так же искал инфу по поводу хуков нажатия клавиш, конечно что то нашёл, то опять же, это только нажатия, из них не получить текст(или объект), который копировали. Короче пока ничего.

Comment: Начните отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/621577/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP всё что мне надо было я нашёл по ссылке https://web.archive.org/web/20131104125500/http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx из вашей ссылки выше. Спасибо.

Comment: Напишите ответ, будет полезно для будущих искателей